# How to calculate the average of the sum of 10 random rolled dices

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, average, dice

The program gonna rolls 10 fair dice (six sided) until the sum of these rolls is prime and larger or equal to 45 and then output the average of the sum of all these rolls. I am trying to use a while loop. Here is what I have until now:

```
import random

# function to generate a random number between 1 and 6
def rollDice():
    roll = random.randint(1,6)
    return roll

for i in range(10):
    print(rollDice(), end = ' ')
# checks if the sum of the dices value is prime
def is_prime(dices):
    total_sum = sum(dices)
    for x in range(2,int(total_sum**0.5)+1):
        if total_sum % x == 0:
            return False
    return True

total_sum = 0
isPrime = False
while isPrime is False or total_sum < 45:
    dices = [rollDice() for dice in range(10)]
    total_sum = sum(dices)
    isPrime = is_prime(dices)

print('Average of the sum of the ten-rolls is {0:.2f}'.format(float(total_sum)/10))
```

The problem is sometimes I run the program the sum of those 10 rolls is not larger than 45, and the Average of those sums are somehow always equal 4.70 no matter what

The output supposed to be: *display 10 random numbers from 1-6* Average of the sum of the ten-rolls is ...

Comment: I ran this a couple of times, and I got different values as well.

Comment: How come you print out 10 random rolls, then you do all your calculation on a different 10 random rolls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dice rolls your are printing is simply not the one that you have at the end of the loop. Delete the lines with `print(rollDice())`.
You'd better print the roll at the end of the code if your really want to see it.

About the average being always 4.7 it is simply because you don't have much choice of prime numbers between 45 and 60 (your maximum with 10 dices). It can be 47, 53, 59.

I didn't do the maths now, but it's pretty clear that 59 is the least probable of the combination (you have just 1 combination possible, that is 9 times 6 + 1 time 5, so probability is (1/6)^10), while 47 appears to be the most probable outcome.